# How to add a transparency layer using JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a DIV using an externally (I have no control over this image) sourced image that is dynamically generated.  It uses a white background image.  I want to convert this on the fly to a transparent background.

So far I'm using 'opacity:0.5' as a CSS rule to make it partially transparent, at the cost of making the data on display in the image also transparent.  Is there a better way to change the white pixels to transparent ones?

I do not wish to use jquery for just this one task, and rewriting this div as a canvas is undesirable since I'm treating the image in question as a sprite map....so I can trim it on the fly to only show the desired section.

CSS:
  `#localweather                                                                                        {left:336px; top:661px; width:267px; height:46px}
   #weatherbug                  {position:relative; margin:1.5px auto; border:1px solid black; height:27px; width:158px; border-radius:7px; opacity:0.5}`

HTML:

`<DIV CLASS='double' ID='localweather'>
    <P CLASS='header'>Local Weather</P>
    <DIV ID='weatherbug'></DIV>
   </DIV>`

JavaScript (Function being called once per second to update the entire page's contents - relevant section only):

`document.getElementById('weatherbug').style.background = "url('http://weathersticker.wunderground.com/weathersticker/cgi-bin/banner/ban/wxBanner?bannertype=wu_simplewhite&airportcode=KTTN&ForcedCity=Princeton&ForcedState=NJ&zip=08540&language=EN') repeat scroll -1px -24px transparent";`

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: @LcSalazar: Editing my question appropriately to show the CSS, JS, and HTML currently in use.

Comment: It is not possible to do what you want without manipulating the image further.  If you can do this, you can easily make white pixels transparent if it's a gif, or add alpha transparency where white exists with something like gd library.

Comment: @Phil_1984_: I suspected as much but it's always best to ask an expert before deciding it's beyond the language's capabilities.

Comment: Well I wont completely rule it out.  Of course it may be implemented using a custom filter with custom browser plugin :) but I certainly haven't heard of anything that does it natively.  Browser support for filters is still pretty bad.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Answer (score 0):

You can make one pixel transparent (with photoshop or other software) and after make a div hover the div to mask with your pixel as background repeat For example I have use it you can use if you want : http://www.spar.fr/charte/base/fond_popUp.png

After you can use hover with css

Comment: This would not work for me.  I need to dynamically alter the image within the browser environment.  The external source updates this image once per hour.

Comment: Adding a layer of transparency over the top will actually do nothing.  I think the OP wants to make his white areas transparent.

Comment: Ok sorry I have not understand like this :) so you can ignore my answer